# Performance impact field-order

Tags: performance, mariadb, query-performance

I'm building a Go-based system, with MariaDB as the storage back-end. As the responses from MariaDB/MySQL are the slowest part of the whole application I was wondering a specific thing;

Does the field order in a query matter? Say I have this simpler query (but might be much bigger):

```
SELECT u.*, cu.FirstName, cu.Surname, uu.FirstName, uu.Surname
FROM UserContact u
LEFT JOIN User cu ON cu.ID = u.CreatedByID
LEFT JOIN User uu ON uu.ID = u.UpdatedByID
WHERE u.UserID = ?
```

Would `u.*` be faster before or after the custom fields? Or would the query optimiser tweak it correctly?

It might be trivial speed differentials, but I really care about speed, and as a SQL query easily has up to 1ms response time in my app's requests that normally are only a few microseconds themselves; every tweak in the usage of the SQL queries might be a big help in the overall performance of the system. I'm already buffering a lot of queried data with (in)validated cache, but sometimes in the back-end still need to run custom logic.

I can't test the performance in a Go benchmark at the moment, as in the latest macOS High Sierra the whole OS kernel panics on a filesystem crash  if the `mysqld` gets called too excessively.

Comment: The vast majority of database systems are disk limited! Check out your execution plan with the field order changed. I don't think it will make much of a difference. You could take a timestamp before and after query execution to "factor out" the database? Not much comfort I know, but "yae cannae beat the laws o' physics Jim!" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of things in `SELECT ...` does not matter.

The main performance killers:

1. Having to fetch from disk.
2. Fetching more rows than needed.
3. Fetching more columns than needed.  That is, `SELECTing` `*` when you don't need all the columns.
4. Everything else is relatively insignificant -- expressions, ordering, etc.

In particular...

```
FROM UserContact u
LEFT JOIN User cu ON cu.ID = u.CreatedByID
LEFT JOIN User uu ON uu.ID = u.UpdatedByID
WHERE u.UserID = ?
```

Needs these indexes to tackle #2, above (unless they are already the PRIMARY KEYs)

```
UserContact: INDEX(UserID)
User:  INDEX(ID)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you need to discuss further.